# Problems with creating a list

Tags: c, list

Im creating a list that reads datas from a file and for each line of the file it creates a new element of the list.

Actually it blockes at Prod_ptr corrente_ptr = *lptr; for some reasons that i cant understand

Main of the program until the loop where i create the list:

```
int main (){
Prod_ptr *lptr = NULL ;
int count, i =  0 ;
char c;
short opzione;
    FILE *file_ptr;
void (*f[DIM])(Prod_ptr *lptr ) ={cambia_quantita , insert_prod, delete_prod ,  cambia_prezzo , cerca_prodotto , stampa_prod};
    file_ptr= fopen( "pischelletto.csv" , "r");
if(file_ptr==NULL) {
    printf("error program name");
    return 1;
}

for (c = getc(file_ptr); c != EOF; c = getc(file_ptr))
    if (c == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline 
        count = count + 1; 

rewind(file_ptr);
for ( i =  0 ;  i < count ; i++ ){
    create_list_prod ( lptr , file_ptr);
}
```

The function that creates the list:

```
void create_list_prod ( Prod_ptr *lptr, FILE *file_ptr){
int code, price;
char nome[20];
    Prod_ptr nuovo_prod_ptr = malloc(sizeof(Lista_prodotti));
    fscanf( file_ptr , "%d;%s;%d;", &code , &nome , &price);
    if(nuovo_prod_ptr != NULL){
        nuovo_prod_ptr->product.codice = code;
        strcpy(nuovo_prod_ptr->product.nome_prod , nome);
        nuovo_prod_ptr->product.prezzo;
        nuovo_prod_ptr->product.quantita_magazzino = rand() % (100001); 
        nuovo_prod_ptr->prossimo_prod_ptr= NULL;

        Prod_ptr precedente_ptr = NULL;
        Prod_ptr corrente_ptr = *lptr;

            while( corrente_ptr != NULL || corrente_ptr->product.codice < nuovo_prod_ptr->product.codice){
                precedente_ptr = corrente_ptr;
                corrente_ptr = corrente_ptr->prossimo_prod_ptr;
        }
        if( precedente_ptr== NULL){
            nuovo_prod_ptr->prossimo_prod_ptr = *lptr;
            *lptr =  nuovo_prod_ptr;
        }
        else{
            precedente_ptr->prossimo_prod_ptr= nuovo_prod_ptr;
            nuovo_prod_ptr->prossimo_prod_ptr = corrente_ptr;
        }

}
else{
    puts("Memoria esaurita");
}
```

}

Comment: Please turn this into a [mcve]. Maybe improve the question like this https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/

Answer (score 4):

in *main*

```
Prod_ptr *lptr = NULL ;

.. lptr not changed

for ( i =  0 ;  i < count ; i++ ){
  create_list_prod ( lptr , file_ptr);
}
```

so you call `create_list_prod` with a *lptr* == NULL, and *lptr* is still NULL when you do `Prod_ptr corrente_ptr = *lptr;` so you read at the address 0 => crash

for me the line must be `Prod_ptr corrente_ptr = lptr;`

---

you also have a problem in the line

```
while( corrente_ptr != NULL || corrente_ptr->product.codice < nuovo_prod_ptr->product.codice)
```

because if `corrente_ptr` is NULL you do `corrente_ptr->product.codice` etc.

Must be

```
while( corrente_ptr != NULL && corrente_ptr->product.codice < nuovo_prod_ptr->product.codice)
```

---

Note that the line `nuovo_prod_ptr->product.prezzo;` does nothing

---

In a previous version I said :

> In the lines
>
> ```
>  nuovo_prod_ptr->prossimo_prod_ptr = *lptr;
>  *lptr =  nuovo_prod_ptr;
> ```
>
> must be
>
> ```
>  nuovo_prod_ptr->prossimo_prod_ptr = lptr;
>  lptr =  nuovo_prod_ptr;
> ```

but I was wrong

---

You do not given the definition of Prod_Ptr etc, so I extrapolate them below from your code.

I added comments in your code to explain additional changes I did to allow it to works well.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* 
   extrapolated definitions
*/

typedef struct Product {
  char nome_prod[20];
  int codice;
  int prezzo;
  int quantita_magazzino;
} Product;

typedef struct Lista_prodotti {
  struct Lista_prodotti * prossimo_prod_ptr;
  Product product;
}Lista_prodotti;

typedef Lista_prodotti * Prod_ptr;

/* */

void create_list_prod ( Prod_ptr *lptr, FILE *file_ptr) {
  int code, price;
  char nome[20];

  if (fscanf(file_ptr , "%d;%19[^;];%d;", &code , nome , &price) != 3) {
    puts("invalid values in the file, bypassed");
  }
  else {
    Prod_ptr nuovo_prod_ptr = malloc(sizeof(Lista_prodotti));

    if (nuovo_prod_ptr != NULL) {
      nuovo_prod_ptr->product.codice = code;
      strcpy(nuovo_prod_ptr->product.nome_prod , nome);
      nuovo_prod_ptr->product.prezzo = price;  /* I suppose */
      nuovo_prod_ptr->product.quantita_magazzino = rand() % (100001); 
      nuovo_prod_ptr->prossimo_prod_ptr= NULL;

      if (*lptr == NULL) {
        /* this is the first added cell of the list */
        *lptr = nuovo_prod_ptr;
      }
      else {
        Prod_ptr precedente_ptr = NULL;
        Prod_ptr corrente_ptr = *lptr;

        while( corrente_ptr != NULL && corrente_ptr->product.codice < nuovo_prod_ptr->product.codice){
          precedente_ptr = corrente_ptr;
          corrente_ptr = corrente_ptr->prossimo_prod_ptr;
        }
        if( precedente_ptr== NULL){
          nuovo_prod_ptr->prossimo_prod_ptr = *lptr;
          *lptr =  nuovo_prod_ptr;
        }
        else{
          precedente_ptr->prossimo_prod_ptr= nuovo_prod_ptr;
          nuovo_prod_ptr->prossimo_prod_ptr = corrente_ptr;
        }
      }
    }
    else{
      puts("Memoria esaurita");
    }
  }
}

int main (){
  Prod_ptr lptr = NULL; /* not "Prod_ptr *" */
  int count = 0, i; /* count must be initialized, not i */
  int c; /* must be an int rather than a char to be able to memorize EOF whatever it is */
  /* put in comment because not used : short opzione; */
  FILE *file_ptr;
  /* put in comment because not used : void (*f[DIM])(Prod_ptr *lptr ) ={cambia_quantita , insert_prod, delete_prod ,  cambia_prezzo , cerca_prodotto , stampa_prod}; */
  file_ptr= fopen( "pischelletto.csv" , "r");

  if(file_ptr==NULL) {
    printf("error program name");
    return 1;
  }

  for (c = getc(file_ptr); c != EOF; c = getc(file_ptr))
    if (c == '\n') // Increment count if this character is newline 
      count = count + 1; 

  rewind(file_ptr);

  for ( i =  0 ;  i < count ; i++ ){
    create_list_prod ( &lptr , file_ptr); /* give the address of lptr */
  }

  fclose(file_ptr); /* added */

  /* print the list to check, also free memory. 
     You may need to adapt if my extrapolated definitions are wrong  */
  while (lptr != NULL) {
    printf("%s : %d %d %d\n", 
           lptr->product.nome_prod,
           lptr->product.codice,
           lptr->product.prezzo,
           lptr->product.quantita_magazzino);
    Prod_ptr next = lptr->prossimo_prod_ptr;
    free(lptr);
    lptr = next;
  }

  return 0;
}
```

If I put that contents in `pischelletto.csv`

```
12;aze;3;
34;qsd;2;
6;foo;123;
```

the execution produces :

```
foo : 6 123 75961
aze : 12 3 71341
qsd : 34 2 22417
```

Executing under *valgrind* to check memory access / memory leaks :

```
valgrind --leak-check=full ./a.out
==22125== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22125== Copyright (C) 2002-2012, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22125== Using Valgrind-3.8.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22125== Command: ./a.out
==22125== 
foo : 6 123 75961
aze : 12 3 71341
qsd : 34 2 22417
==22125== 
==22125== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22125==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==22125==   total heap usage: 4 allocs, 4 frees, 688 bytes allocated
==22125== 
==22125== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==22125== 
==22125== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==22125== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 6 from 6)
```

Comment: thank u , u actually solved the problems involved with pointers and now it "works". Can i ask you how can i not lose the created cell?

Comment: Im new to lists and from the material given me by university i cant really understand why and how to fix it

Comment: @GiacomoMasciarelli did you apply exactly all my remarks or something different ? I need to know otherwise I will not reason from the right definition

Comment: yes i did apply all of your remarks as u explained and wrote them

Comment: @GiacomoMasciarelli I edited my answer with a full proposal and execution results. Some of my previous remarks was wrong